# Add record to ACF Field group programatically

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I've created a Field Group using ACF. All the fields are simple text fields. I now want some way to create a function that can add a record using php code. How is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
update_field( 'my_field', 'my_value', $post_id );
```

Here is the source: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/